# How to get IP address for rate limiting in Actix-Web?

Tags: rust, actix-web

I'm trying to implement a rate-limiter based on IP address, in a websocket application, but I can't figure out how to get the IP address as a string. I've been scouring the docs and there's no mention of IP address.

I have a `addr: Recipient<WSMessage>` and a context.

So far I've tried `ctx.address()` - Can't convert to string
`msg.addr.tx.0` - Can't unbox bc its private.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out:

```
fn chat_route(req: &HttpRequest<WsChatSessionState>) -> Result<HttpResponse, Error> {
    ws::start(
        req,
        WSSession {
            id: 0,
            hb: Instant::now(),
            ip: req.connection_info().remote().to_string(),
        },
    )
}
```